# Spring boot 3 Junit 5 Integration Test Error Creating bean with name error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I have verified that the CandidateRepository works correctly, by running unit tests for it. However, when I try to run the integration test for the CandidateController, I keep getting an error that says "No qualifying bean of type 'CandidateRepository' available". I'm not sure why this is happening since I have already included the necessary annotations (@Repository, @Service, and @RestController) and component scanning in my code. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateController' defined in file [D:\java_repos\micro-library\machine_learning_java\talent-sourcing-system\build\classes\java\main\com\tss\talentsourcingsystem\application\candidate\controller\CandidateController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'candidateServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\java_repos\micro-library\machine_learning_java\talent-sourcing-system\build\classes\java\main\com\tss\talentsourcingsystem\application\candidate\service\impl\CandidateServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tss.talentsourcingsystem.application.candidate.repository.CandidateRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here is the code for my integration test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class CandidateControllerIntegrationTest {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/candidates";

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CandidateService candidateService;

    @Autowired
    private CandidateController candidateController;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    // tests here

}
```

How can I resolve this error and make my integration test pass? I try alread MockBean

Comment: First, you don't need to instantiate the repository, the service and the controller. The use of `@SpringBootTest` will automatically load all those classes in the context. You should put the `@Service` on your `CandidateServiceImpl` class. Can you post the other classes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put @Service and @Transactional above CandidateServiceImpl class.